# How do I properly store and load .jks on to my Java/Spring microservice?

Tags: spring, docker, security, aws-secrets-manager

I need to store/load a separate JKS file for a very specific 3rd party integration on one of my microservices (Spring/JAVA). Those key/certificate pairs should be used by a separate background task that should call 3rd party servers once in a while using custom black box SDK. This SDK requires a path to JKS file as one of input params, so it must be physically stored on disk.

The simplest approach I am going with for now: JKS stored in git under resources folder, then password supplied to docker container through some custom terraform script.
How bad/not secure is this? Assuming repo is private github.

I think another options might be (considering docker/terraform run by jenkins builder, deployed to aws ecs):

1. Load at runtime from aws secret manager/encrypted s3 then store on filesystem.
2. Somehow supply at image building stage.
3. Somehow supply at container startup stage.

Now the question is, how do I properly store and load this JKS on my service? What wold be the best way and would be the minimum acceptable way?

Answer (score 0):

If we go full enterprise security mode, developers shouldn't even have access to that JKS file.

For development, they should get a different JKS file that gives them just enough permissions to do their development work.

To get a file that is only accessible at runtime from a running Docker image, you can put it on a Volume that is only mounted in production, and managed separately from your normal development deployments.

If you use Docker Swarm or Docker Compose, you can define it as an external [Docker secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/), and your file will be available under `/run/secrets/my_secret.jks`.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    secrets:
      - my_secret_jks
secrets:
  my_secret_jks:
    external: true
```

If you use Kubernetes, you can store the file as a Kubernetes Secret and [mount it as a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume) of type `secret`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        # name must match the volume name below
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /etc/secret-volume
          readOnly: true
  # The secret data is exposed to Containers in the Pod through a Volume.
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: test-secret
```